# Does Flurry of Blows count as an attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, monk

[This handbook](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25065021/No_Paper_Tigers!!!!:_The_Monk_Handbook) suggests that **Flurry of Blows** is an attack when recommending the otherwise extremely underwhelming malec-keth janissary:

> Malec-Keth Janissary (Swordmage-MoP)- Add extra damage to all attacks.  As this can be thunder damage, it can be combined with Resounding Thunder.  I also believe the extra damage is applied to FoB, as FoB is also an attack.  The rest of the path is pretty worthless, but you don't need anything else.
>
> Primordial Blade (16th level): Years of tireless study and exposure to the forces within the Elemental Chaos have honed your ability to control the elements. At the end of each short rest or extended rest, select one of the following damage types: cold, fire, thunder, or lightning. Your attacks deal 1d4 extra damage of the selected damage type until the end of your next rest.
>
> Centered Flurry of Blows
> Your fists become a blur as you follow up your initial attack with another, shifting your foes’ positions to your advantage.
> At-Will        Psionic
> No Action      Melee 1
> Trigger: You hit with an attack during your turn
> Target: One creature
> Level 11: One or two creatures
> Level 21: Each enemy adjacent to you
> Effect: The target takes damage equal to 2 + your Wisdom modifier, and you slide it 1 square to a square adjacent to you, or 1 square in any direction if the target wasn’t targeted by the triggering attack.
> Special: You can use this power only once per round.

**Flurry of Blows** is listed as a "monk feature."

Does **Flurry of Blows** count as an attack for purposes of **Primordial Blade**?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes, as per Player's Handbook FAQ**

Found reference [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25890329/Flurry_of_Blows_in_light_of_Rules_Compendium_change.&post_num=5#467007469):

> Attack powers that have a target line and deal damage are attacks (See: Magic Missile). Ergo, Flurry of Blows is an attack.
>
> This is clarified in the FAQ for Player's Handbook, in case anyone was wondering where it's coming from.

And the relevant original text is [here](http://wizards.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1396/~/faq-for-the-player%27s-handbook!) (item 38):

> 1. What happens if I use magic missile while benefiting from a power like greater invisibility? Does it count as an attack and would my invisibility end?
>
> Yes, it does, and yes, it would. The initial use of any attack power that has a target line, an attack line, or both counts as making an attack. Because of this fact, using an attack power like the fighter's rain of steel does not count as making an attack, since the power has neither a target line nor an attack line

Comment: Hmmm "Attack powers that ... are attacks" ... so I don't think the Magic Missile discussion applies, as it is a "Wizard Attack" and a power, while FoB is a "Monk Feature" and a power.

Comment: Ahhh... but, Rules Compendium p90 indicates that powers that deal damage are attack powers. Which overrules my objection.

Comment: Now, to be clear, it doesn't have any useful keywords for normal slide-stacking techniques, nor does it have an attack... so it's depressingly difficult to buff.